# Validar campos dinamicos clonados. Parsley y laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

Tengo un formulario en el cual puedo agregar, en mi caso, lineas de pedido.
Ésto lo hago con JQuery, clonando toda la línea.
 Uso laravel 5.1 para el back-end y para el client-side estoy ocupando una librería Javascript de forms llamada parsley. Al momento de hacer validación por parte del servidor no hay ningun problema, pero al momento de hacerlo por client-side con parsley no puedo hacer que mis elementos pueda validarlos por separado.
No se si me doy a entender. 
Adjunto fotos para que se hagan una idea.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de agregar linea

```
$("#addRow").on("click",function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();   

$("#tabla tr:last").clone().find("input, select").val('').each(function() {
  }).end().appendTo("#tabla"); 

  });
```

Codigo form vista

```
{!!Form::open(['route'=>'venta.store', 'id'=>'forma','method'=>'POST','data-parsley-validate'=>'parsley-validate'])!!} 

@include('venta.forms.venta')

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

elemento input blade

```
<td width="17%">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="vtcanp[]" required /> 

</td>
```

El problema es que cuando genero mas de una linea y quiero validar estas lineas nuevas y pongo algún valor, sigue dándome problemas que no hay un valor siendo que agrego uno como sale en la foto que puse. Espero se entienda

Comment: Deberías incluir el código mínimo que genera el problema...

Comment: Estimado agregue parte del código..el problema es que cuando genero mas lineas (ver la foto) sigue acusándome que los campos están vacíos siendo que no lo están (ver foto de la pregunta), ese es el problema. Necesito que la librería parsley de alguna manera evalúe los campos creados cada uno .
Saludos

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no puedes duplicar los id's, es decir deben ser únicos

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar  regular expression en html. como estas usando JavaScript supongo que estas usando HTML.

por ejemplo mira este ejemplo..

```
<form action="somefile.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" pattern="[a-z]{1,15}">
</form>
```

Te dejo unos links que busque para aplicarlos en la web,

http://web.ontuts.com/snippets/10-expresiones-regulares-imprescindibles-en-desarrollo-web/

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145

http://www.contadordecaracteres.info/prueba-expresiones-regulares.html

Comment: Tu respuesta no está relacionado con el OP

Comment: Estimado el problema es que cuando genero mas lineas (ver la foto) sigue acusándome que los campos están vacíos siendo que no lo están (ver foto de la pregunta), ese es el problema. Necesito que la librería parsley de alguna manera evalúe los campos creados cada uno . Saludos

Comment: Como comentario aparte, los enlaces compartidos parecerían estar dando soluciones simples, pero en mi opinión no recomendaría usar a prácticamente **ninguna** de las expresiones regulares publicadas. A simple vista tienen errores importantes. En cambio, recomendaría leer los enlaces que están en http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info